# Creating Sprite image with items from static folder in AWS

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, amazon-s3, css-sprites

I have a static folder with images in an AWS Server and I need to create (and update) a sprite image every time when I send a Image to the server(via FTP), and save it's positions in JSON to send to a web service. Actually, I load these images with Ajax called with Jquery in a Django Project, who works usually in Internet Explorer and because this, it loads slowly and some imagens dont load always, and the user need to refresh the page. Anyone have a suggestion how to create the sprite?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you directly store the sprite as a static asset on AWS S3? If you really need to create a sprite from single images on the client side then use something like [Spritely](http://www.spritely.net/)

Comment: I dont want to make a effect, I want to load a gallery of images in a uniform time, but it usually dont load all the images or load one fast, another slow and so wait.